# How to scroll down a sub-section in Selenium (C#)?

Tags: c#, html, css, selenium

I am UI-testing a web page with a grid on it, using Selenium Webdriver in C#.

The grid has its own scroll bar and I would like to scroll down to the bottom of the grid to check a certain result has appeared when I add it through a modal form (the UI test is currently failing as it can't see the result until I scroll down).

How do I target the scroll bar on the grid as opposed to the normal scroll bar on the main webpage? This is the HTML of my grid's scroll bar:

```
<div class="ScrollbarLayout_face ScrollbarLayout_faceVertical public_Scrollbar_face" style="height: 367.38px; transform: translate3d(0px, 148.535px, 0px); backface-visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

I was thinking of using the below code, but I can't think how to target an element at the bottom of the grid to scroll to?

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

Comment: You should try javascript function [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to reach that perticaular element as `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", driver.FindElement(By.id("my-id")));`

Comment: This is my problem - if I could target or find the element in the first place, I wouldn't need to scroll down. My UI test is failing because the element can't be viewed, even though it is there at the bottom of the grid, just out of sight.

Comment: If you want to scroll when it's need you can check `element.Displayed` property to determine scrolling or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set focus to any object of grid by using any event

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")).Click();
```

Then add below two lines:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.End).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Thanks very much this answer basically did it for me.

What I needed to do was target the scroll bar and click on it once to activate it. I then sent the "Page Down" command through actions (End didn't work for some reason) and this worked.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try to perform the action on that element without scrolling down up to there. 
That is, get the element by findElement() and perform your action on it without scrolling the page.

Comment: That's initially what I tried to do. My grid has a property, rows, which store all the rows and their information.

So when I add a new row, my retrieving code (pseudo) looks like: MyGrid.Rows.First( row => row.Text == "Random string")

When I debug with breakpoints, I look at the MyGrid.Rows object and all the rows are in there. On closer inspection, the rows that are not visible in the grid (i.e the ones that need to be scrolled to to be visible), appear in the MyGrid.Rows object but with all its values as blank strings.

Comment: Also, if I can find the element in the first place, that means my UI test would be passing! My UI test checks the rows in my grid for matching elements eg. MyGrid.Rows.First.Should().Be("Random string");

Comment: try this
 Mouse.MoveScrollWheel(UITestControl, Int32), where "UITestControl" will be your grid control

Comment: try this if ...Wheel() not worked then ScrollToView(element)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this thanks to help from user nikhilp:

a) Targeting the scroll bar's XPath

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"myGrid\"]/div/div/div[2]/div"))
```

b) Clicking the scroll bar once to activate it

```
.Click()
```

c) Sending the Page Down command

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
actions.SendKeys(Keys.PageDown).Build().Perform();
```